# Failed to connect to rslr.connectbind.com port 8080: Connection refused

Tags: php

PHP CURL is refusing to open connection

When I call this url on a browser its opens and send an sms

http://rslr.connectbind.com:8080/bulksms/bulksms?username=josy-mbongocash&password=kipese73&type=0&dlr=1&destination=254719401837&source=MbongoCash&message=METHODE-PATRICK

Response OK : 1701|254719401837|e8fbf5af-d7c2-4f34-a80f-94803ffee9d5

when I try calling it with curl

```
$curl = curl_init();
curl_setopt_array($curl, array(
CURLOPT_PORT => "8080",
CURLOPT_URL => "http://rslr.connectbind.com:8080/bulksms/bulksms?
username=josy-
mbongocash&password=kipese73&type=0&dlr=1&destination=254719401837&
source=MbongoCash&message=METHODE-PATRICK",
CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER => true,
CURLOPT_ENCODING => "",
CURLOPT_MAXREDIRS => 10,
CURLOPT_TIMEOUT => 30,
CURLOPT_HTTP_VERSION => CURL_HTTP_VERSION_1_1,
CURLOPT_CUSTOMREQUEST => "GET",
CURLOPT_HTTPHEADER => array(
"Postman-Token: 09ba239d-fcb7-4755-8032-7ff4f768147f",
"cache-control: no-cache"
),
));
 $response = curl_exec($curl);
 $err = curl_error($curl);

 curl_close($curl);

 if ($err) {
 echo "cURL Error #:" . $err;
} else {
echo $response;
}
```

RESPONSE :Failed to connect to rslr.connectbind.com port 8080: Connection refused

Comment: First off unsure how that site works but just making sure you're aware your login/password are in there.

Comment: Please avoid posting your personal login details like username and passwords on stack-overflow.

Answer (score 1):

With CURL

```
$url="http://rslr.connectbind.com/bulksms/bulksms";
$ch = curl_init();

$variables = array(
    'username' => 'Your user name',
    'password' => 'Your password',
    'type' => '0',
    'dlr' => '1',
    'destination' => "Mobile number with country code", 
    'source' => 'Brand Name',
    'message' => "sms",
);

curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, $url);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 0);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $variables);

echo $result = curl_exec($ch);
```

Without CURL

```
$url="http://rslr.connectbind.com/bulksms/bulksms";
$variables = array(
    'username' => 'Your user name',
    'password' => 'Your password',
    'type' => '0',
    'dlr' => '1',
    'destination' => "Mobile number with country code", 
    'source' => 'Brand Name',
    'message' => "sms",
);

$options = array(
    'http' => array(
        'header'  => "Content-type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded\r\n",
        'method'  => 'POST',
        'content' => http_build_query($variables),
    ),
);


$context  = stream_context_create($options);
echo $result = file_get_contents($url, false, $context);
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue was the port I changed and it worked

Comment: Can you be a bit more specific about what port you changed? Running into a similar issue with the service.